# Unable to connect to Mobile Broadband: Huawei EC1260 - TATA Photon+

Tags: networking

I have a TATA Photon+ (Huawei EC1260) mobile broadband device and am unable to establish a connection either using wvdial or the network manager.

Here is my wvdial.conf

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
stupid Mode = 1
Modem Type = Analog Modem
ISDN = 0
Phone = #777
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Username = internet
Password = internet
Baud = 9600
```

and here some info from /var/log/messages

```
Sep 30 15:45:27 owais-laptop kernel: [ 3130.499111] usb 6-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Sep 30 15:45:27 owais-laptop kernel: [ 3130.509143] scsi44 : usb-storage 6-1:1.3
Sep 30 15:45:28 owais-laptop kernel: [ 3131.517057] scsi 44:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Sep 30 15:45:28 owais-laptop kernel: [ 3131.519980] scsi 44:0:0:1: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   SD Storage       2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Sep 30 15:45:28 owais-laptop usb_modeswitch: switched to 12d1:140b (HUAÿWEI TECHNOLOGIES: HUAWEI Mobile)
Sep 30 15:45:28 owais-laptop kernel: [ 3131.548883] sr1: scsi-1 drive
Sep 30 15:45:28 owais-laptop kernel: [ 3131.549148] sr 44:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
Sep 30 15:45:28 owais-laptop kernel: [ 3131.550627] sd 44:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Sep 30 15:45:28 owais-laptop kernel: [ 3131.591897] sd 44:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Sep 30 15:47:31 owais-laptop pppd[22151]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Sep 30 15:47:31 owais-laptop pppd[22151]: Using interface ppp0
Sep 30 15:47:31 owais-laptop pppd[22151]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB0
Sep 30 15:48:01 owais-laptop pppd[22151]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Sep 30 15:48:01 owais-laptop pppd[22151]: Connection terminated.
Sep 30 15:48:01 owais-laptop pppd[22151]: Receive serial link is not 8-bit clean:
Sep 30 15:48:01 owais-laptop pppd[22151]: Problem: all had bit 7 set to 0
Sep 30 15:48:01 owais-laptop pppd[22151]: Modem hangup
Sep 30 15:48:01 owais-laptop pppd[22151]: Exit.
```

Is this a network problem or device problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right. Looks like it was a network problem. nothing wrong with the device or the setup.

Comment: How to resolve this issue? I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Huawei EC1260 - TATA Photon+